# How to hide common line between two geofence polygon

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have common line between two geofence polygon . I want to hide this common line and merge two geofence area into one. The scenario has been shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9JyN.jpg) image.